# How can i "remove" item from list without .remove?

Tags: c#

I have a list of byte[] that is being filled by one thread, and then i have another thread that is reading from that list and sending the items trough the network.[image]

I want to every time i read an item in thread2 to clear it from memory. But since i am using threads, if i use .remove i will have to deal with changing the index of the list, and not letting thread1 write to it while i am doing that. So, so i don't interfire with the index of the list, i am just changing the item that i am done using to **null**. What is the best way to do this so that it does not waste space in memory?

Comment: Why not use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

A `ConcurrentQueue` is a thread-safe first-in/first-out collection, so the first thread would push items into the queue with [`Enqueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287262(v=vs.110).aspx) while the second thread would try to read items from that queue with [`TryDequeue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: When i use `TryDeQueue` and it reads successfully, does it erase it from the Queue ?

Comment: @meme yes. TryDequeue tries to remove and return the object at the beginning of the concurrent queue.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It helped a ton. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on question it sounds like assignment for critical sections (aka `lock`).

Create lock object and perform read/write under `lock`:

```
object lockList = new object();

byte ReadFromList(int index) 
{
  lock(lockList) { return theList[index]; }
}

void RemoveFromList(int index) 
{
  lock(lockList) { theList.Remove(index); }
}
```

Note that usually for consumer/producer you'd use [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx).